# Показать select после выбора

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Есть два select.

```html
echo 'Производитель<select id="man" name="Manuf_Name" class = "man">';
 
$sql=mysql_query("select * from `manufacturer` ");
 
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 print "<option value = $result[Manuf_Name]> $result[Manuf_Name]</option>";
 
 }
echo '</select>';
```

И второй

```html
echo 'Модель <select name="sub_name">';
 
$sql=mysql_query("select `sub_name` from `mark` where `Manuf_Name` =  $manuf");
 
while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($sql)):
 print "<option> $result1[sub_name]</option>";
 endwhile; 
 
 echo '</select>';
```

Когда я выбираю Производителя мне нужны только его модели. То есть при выборе Aston martin мне не нужны модели мерседеса.
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно предложить 2 основных направления решения этой ситуации:

1) с перезагрузкой страницы: вы делаете на странице форму с селектом, выбранный селект постите, на стороне сервера проверяете выбранный элемент и показываете, соответственно, нужную выборку уже на отображаемой странице.

2) без перезагрузки страницы:

2.1) вы записываете все значения в массивы js, из которых потом формируете селекты;

2.2) пользуетесь технологией ajax: отправляете выбранное значение селекта посредством js к себе на пхп скрипт, там обрабатываете и отправляете ответ, а на странице этим ответом обновляете селект.

Не забудьте подключить JQuery к page.php. Так же обратите внимания, что обеим этим файлам не хватает инициализации подключения к базе данных, а, возможно, и чего-то еще, что используется в вашем проекте.

Т.е. эти файлы можно взять в качестве образца и доработать.

**page.php**

```
echo '<form id="MyForm" action="" method="post">';
echo 'Производитель<select id="man" name="Manuf_Name" class = "man"><option value="-1">- Выберите производителя -</option>'; 
$sql=mysql_query("select * from `manufacturer` ");
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    print "<option value = $result[Manuf_Name]> $result[Manuf_Name]</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo 'Модель <select id="mod" name="sub_name"><option value="-1">- Выберите производителя -</option>';
echo '</select>';
echo '<br><button type="submit">Send</button></form>';
echo '
<script>
$("#man").change(function(){
    var form = $("form[name=MyForm]"),
        formData = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "select-mod.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({
            manuf: $(this).val()
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( msg ){
            if(msg.success) {
                $("#mod").html(msg.message);
            }
            else {
                alert(msg.message);
            }
        }
});
$("form[name=MyForm]").submit(function(){
    if ($("#man").val()==-1) {
        alert("Выберите производителя");
        return false;
    }
    if ($("#mod").val()==-1) {
        alert("Выберите модель");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
</script>
';
```

**select-mod.php**

```
$data = array(
    'success' => false,
    'message' => ''
);
if (!isset($_POST['manuf'])) {
    $data['message'] = 'Не передан id производителя';
    return json_encode($data);
}

$sql=mysql_query("select `sub_name` from `mark` where `Manuf_Name` =  $_POST[manuf]");

if (mysql_numrows($sql)==0) {
    $data['message'] = 'Модели не найдены';
    return json_encode($data);
}

$data['success'] = true;
while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($sql)):
    $data['message'] .= "<option> $result1[sub_name]</option>";
endwhile;
return json_encode($data);
```